# Will performance drop down by using multisampled OpenGL context with multisampling off?

Tags: opengl, multisampling

Create a multisampled OpenGL context, turn off multisampling by glDisable, compare to using non-multisampled context, how performance are affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSAA ( or FSAA) level definitely  affects the performance.Just make a basic OpenGL app with several primitives (preferably of big size so that fragment shader would have to do a lot of work),and you will notice performance drop.Of course it depends on you hardware specs but yes ,there is a noticeable impact after all.Why does that happen?Because the pixels are sampled multiple times which means more work for fragment shader.Read [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling) for a thorough explanation .

Comment: You didn't answer the op's question. If you enable a multisampled context/view but turn off multisampling with glDisable, is it as if you never created an MSAA context/view to begin with? Or is there still a penalty?

Comment: glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE) has an effect to custom (offscreen) FBOs.Setting your display context to be multisample causes your default FBO to be such and it is not affected by glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)

Comment: Thanx for the clarification! Stackoverflow > documentation ;-)